# Why does heating an atom make it emit certain frequencies?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons

We're going over quantum basics in chemistry right now and I'm very confused.

Electrons can only accept in discreet quanta to move up an energy level, right? And they reflect other forms of light that don't supply energy in their specific quanta, right? And flame is just infrared electromagnetic radiation, right?

Then when heated by flame, why do the electrons move up to a next energy level? Shouldn't they need a certain wavelength to move up - one that isn't provided by the flame, given the emission for the atom is in the visible light range?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please note discrete vs discreet (https://www.dictionary.com/e/discreet-and-discrete/)

Comment: Flame is not infrared radiation. It is a luminous chemical reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Heat energy is distributed and some of the energy might match the amount required to excite an electron**

There are two parts to the answer.

Firstly, there is more to emission than *electrons* leaping to a new energy level. Molecules can be excited by making them move faster (kinetic energy), vibrate at a different frequency (vibrational energy), rotate faster (rotational energy) and so on. Vibrational energy is quantised (so are others but sometimes the levels are so close together that, in practice, we see a continuum) but the wavelengths of light that match changes are in the infra-red region of light.

One of the effects of putting heat energy into a system is to distribute that energy across all the possible excitations. Each will show a Boltzmann like distribution with some molecules having a lot and other having a little.

Secondly, if there is enough heat a small number of molecules might just, randomly, have enough to match an electronic transition. Perhaps two very fast-moving molecules bang into each other and that matches a specific electronic transition. This means that, even if the *average* energy from the heat source is too low to cause an excitation, there may be a small number of individual molecules that have enough energy.

The reason why heat sometimes causes even electronic emissions is because the heat energy is *distributed* statistically across many molecules and excitation modes. So in a large statistical sample *some* molecules will have the right energy to match the transition. Don't forget those statistics when thinking about what is happening at the molecular level.

Comment: Matt, I am afraid this reasoning that "so in a large statistical sample some molecules will have the right energy to match the transition." is incorrect. I think nobody $knows$ the exact mechanism of this transfer of energy to excite the atoms. The student is asking about atomic emission. It is rare to heat a molecule (in the gas phase) and cause it to show a spectrum. The question is how are we heating the atomized matter in the gas phase. If it is a flame, not only thermal excitation and collisions, but chemical reactions may also cause electronic excitation (e.g. $\ce{NH3-O2}$ flame).

Comment: Also, the temperature would determine how many lines we would see in a spectrum. In a plasma (inductively coupled plasma) certainly there is no chemical reaction but there is a crazy collision process of free atoms with ions and electrons. What is mechanism of this collisional heating? Again, perhaps nobody knows.

Answer (score 2):

Absorbing photons is just one of ways atoms and their electrons, or molecules, can gain energy. Other ways are e.g mechanical collisions and chemical reactions.

Note that atoms do not reflect light they do not absorb, but let it pass through like if they were not there. If they had reflected it,  air would have been an opaque fog. A very small number of photons are dispersed by the [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering?wprov=sfla1), what gives the sky it's blue colour.

A flame  contains mixture of

- atoms
- atomic ions
- free electrons
- molecules
- radicals(molecules with unpaired electrons}
- molecular ions ( and ion radicals )

Atoms and atomic ions do have spectral lines in their emission or absorption spectra, related to particular energies, frequencies and wavelengths ( somewhat broaden, mostly  by the Doppler effect ).

But molecules, radicals and molecular ions have rather broad, diffuse bands.

Photons in UV, VIS and near IR have energies typical for electron excitations/transitions.

Far IR and MW have energies needed to change molecular bond vibrations and bond/molecule rotations, as these are quantized as well.

High energetic collision and mainly chemics reactions frequently lead to a  molecule with excited electron. This energy gets dissipated either as mechanical energy passed to other molecules, or, it can be emitted.

Special cases are free electrons and solid matter in flames, that are not limited to particular frequencies at all.

Electrons can emit photons of any frequency (limited by electron energy ).

Solids ( smoke, large scale atomic structures ) have continuos emission spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you explain a little more why near IR and UV photons cause electron transitions? Do these photons have the right quanta for the atoms they hit?;

Comment: Yes, they do. But particular wavelengths for particular species. Or wavelength bands.